# Is there an UriAgilityPack / UrlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm always trying to figure out some url/uri methodology with asp.net to manipulate a uri/url.

It'd be nice to have:

```
UriAgilityPack uri = new UriAgilityPack("http://some.com/path?query1=value1");
```

or

```
UriAgilityPack uri = new UriAgilityPack().LoadSiteRelative("~/path?query1=value1");
```

Then with

```
enum Schemes {
  Http,
  Https
}

uri.Scheme = Schemes.Https;
```

and/or

```
foreach(QueryItem item in uri.Query)
   // do something with item
```

and/or

```
uri.Query.Add("AddToCart", 5)
```

`string s = uri.ToString()         // https://some.com/path?query1=value1&AddToCart=5`

or

```
string root = uri.RootPath                // /path?query1=value1&AddToCart=5
string relative = uri.RootRelativePath;   // ~/path?query1=value1&AddToCart=5
```

Answer (score 5):

No need for an agility pack for something that's already built into the framework. So start with an [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx):

```
var uri = new Uri("http://some.com/path?query1=value1");
```

and then:

```
Console.WriteLine(uri.Scheme);
```

and then:

```
var nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
foreach (string key in nvc)
{
    Console.WriteLine("key: {0}, value: {1}", key, nvc[key]);
}
```

and then:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
var nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
nvc.Add("AddToCart", "5");
builder.Query = nvc.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

and finally:

```
Console.WriteLine(builder.Uri.PathAndQuery);
```

See how easy it is? And what's even cooler is that you can do this in a desktop application, you don't need ASP.NET at all.

If I had one advice to give you when dealing with urls in .NET it would be to never use string concatenations. Always use the API as it will guarantee you proper encoding and respect of web standards.

Comment: Alright, cool, but they are not all in one, so I have to remember the various ways (still) of manipulating a url.

Comment: @Chuck Savage, for me they are all in one, the *one* being the BCL. I mean do you really need an agility pack for 3 lines of code?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll look into them.  And what is BCL?  (I'm old school, and the B strikes me as Borland... so I can't think beyond that, lol

Comment: @Chuck Savage, BCL stands for [Base Class Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Library). It's basically a set of managed code assemblies that you get for granted once you install the .NET framework.

Comment: I have VS2008, so I suppose I have it?

Comment: @Chuck Savage, oh yeah, you have it, otherwise you wouldn't be able to write a single line of .NET code :-) That's .NET in fact.